# How to use anchored pairs with fonts on Android

Tags: android, fonts, typography, glyph-substitution

**BACKGROUND:**
Font files have some advanced tables embedded in them that allowed glyph substitution, combined forms and anchored pairs.

For English speakers, think about having the 3 characters "1", "/", and "2 and the font automatically combines them into a new glyph that looks like a ½

That was a small **1/2** if it doesn't display correctly for you.

**QUESTION:**
Does anyone know if Android supports these advanced typography tables?